# Stack Search - Chrome extension

Tags: app, questions, search, chrome-extensions

***Stack Search*** is the chrome extension you’ve always dreamed of!

Stack Search adds to your Google Search results a filtered set of the most relevant answers from your top trusted coding sources: StackOverflow and StackExchange. These results are displayed on the right-hand side of the Google SERP, along with links to reach the exact source of the chosen answer.

Additionally, the extension displays a number of answers available under each StackOverflow and StackExchange organic search result, along with a score for the answer and whether the latter has been accepted as reliable.

A quick install will change the way you search for coding help forever! It doesn’t take space nor makes the SERP loading time slower.

[Chrome Extension Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-search/mmbkjfdlhegphofeodeinpbcifaobacl?utm_source=stackapp&utm_medium=post)

[GitHub](https://github.com/DCookieMonster/stack-search)

Comment: This extension *did* change the way I search for code related help. Unfortunately, in Chrome 73 CORB is enabled which means the extension is no longer working.. I wish you'd fix that! :) (https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches)